# My fakefacebook page has "Grails Runtime Exception" How can I get rid of it and get back my page that I had before?

Tags: javascript, grails

I was doing an assignment when all of a sudden...Grails runtime exception appears and has blank all over my page. All my work is lost and I worked so hard. I was almost done when that happened. What is it? And how can I restore my page?
 This is what is written...

```
Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:render>: Error executing tag <g:render>: No row with the given identifier exists: [myfakewall.Friend#155509] at /home/myfakewall2/myfakefb/grails-app/views/post/_partial.gsp:80 at /home/myfakewall2/myfakefb/grails-app/views/wall/edit.gsp:205
Servlet: grails
URI: /grails/wall/edit.dispatch
Exception Message: No row with the given identifier exists: [myfakewall.Friend#155509] 
Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:render>: Error executing tag <g:render>: No row with the given identifier exists: [myfakewall.Friend#155509] at /home/myfakewall2/myfakefb/grails-app/views/post/_partial.gsp:80 at /home/myfakewall2/myfakefb/grails-app/views/wall/edit.gsp:205 
Class: /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/wall/edit.gsp 
At Line: [-1] 
Code Snippet:
```

I have no clue what this means and I would like my page restroed if any of you would so kindly tell me what it is. How to get rid of it?

Comment: I don't think this is a coding question... I think veronica was using a Grails application, and caught an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended that you should include your code in question. But from the error description, it seems you have problem in database-mapping at domain class.

As I guess, you have do something like:

```
class A { 
    String    name
} 

class B {
    A property
    String name
}
```

In this case, if you delete an A record, B can no longer retrieve A, so the error "No row with the given identifier exists" make sense.

The simple solution for this case is deleting all the record B using object A, before you delete an A object. Or you can change your domain settings to use belongsTo & hasMany relationship, which enable delete cascading.

To "restore" your work, I think truncating & re-create the database is enough. You can also use "drop-create" in your dataSource. There's nothing to be panic here.